# Stream Geometry or Path Geometry to create Chart Control

Tags: wpf, polyline

I am building a chart control when drawing the line curve using Stream Geometry class, and using the PloyLineTo function of StreamGeometry Class and passing all the points to it to create the Curve, I have a requirement to add legend to the Curve, i.e some symbol on the line to identify it how do I achieve it using Stream- Geometry, or should I need to use Path Geometry ? Any pointer will be much appreciated.

Comment: You would usually put a control (e.g. TextBlock, Label or ContentControl) at a specific position on the Canvas where you draw your line. PathGeometry won't help with that.

Comment: The control's are placed , I have created a plotter control derived from Canvas, where I will drawing the line, so my question is which is the best way.